# How to scrape the price

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to scrape the price for one specific item?

In the html, there are several divs with `class="pb-current-price"`, however, I'm only interested in the price of `$2,299.99`. How do I do this?

Thanks.

```
                 <div class="pb pb-large-view pb-theme-default">
                  <div class="pb-current-price ">
                   <span class="">
                    $2,299.99
                   </span>
                  </div>
                 </div>

import requests
import bs4 as bs 
from lxml import html

url = ""
agent = {"User-Agent":""}
url_get = requests.get(url,headers=agent) #, cookies=cookies)


tree = html.fromstring(url_get.content)

prices = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pb-sale-price "]/span/text()')
print(prices)
```

Running the code above will return the price as `[]`.

Comment: Did you copy your cookies from your browser as the comment in that code says? That page redirects to a country selection page for the first visit.

Comment: seems cookies are not quite necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on your code. A few things before giving the snippet:

1. you were searching `"pb-sale-price "` instead of `"pb-current-price "`
2. as said in the comments I could not work with your html page so I simulated the answer according to the html snippet you gave us
3. I simulated also another article for the sake of completeness

Now the code:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs 
from lxml import html


# simulating the html answer
string="""
<div class="pb pb-large-view pb-theme-default">
<div class="pb-current-price ">
  <span class="">
  $2,299.99
  </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="pb pb-large-view pb-theme-default">
<div class="pb-current-price ">
  <span class="">
  $799.99
  </span>
</div>
</div>
"""


url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/lg-65-class-oled-b9-series-2160p-smart-4k-uhd-tv-with-hdr/6360611.p?skuId=6360611"
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'}
# cookies = {"cookie":"COPY_HERE_YOUR_COOKIE_FROM_BROWSER"}
#url_get = requests.get(url,headers=agent) #, cookies=cookies)

#tree = html.fromstring(url_get.content)
tree = html.fromstring(string)
#print(html.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))

prices = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pb-current-price "]/span/text()')

# output cleaning
prices = [x.strip(' ,\n') for x in prices]
print(prices)
```

Output

```
['$2,299.99', '$799.99']
```

PS - I strongly suggest you to read also [this beautiful article](https://pythontips.com/2018/06/20/an-intro-to-web-scraping-with-lxml-and-python/)

Answer (score 0):

The price you show is the regular price. You can grab from one of the script tags as follows

```
import requests, json, re

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/lg-65-class-oled-b9-series-2160p-smart-4k-uhd-tv-with-hdr/6360611.p?skuId=6360611&intl=nosplash', headers = headers)
p = re.compile(r'regularPrice\\":([\d.]+),')
price = p.findall(r.text)[0]
print(price)
```